# Change dragging cursor

Tags: css

How to change cursor when dragging using **only CSS?**

```
div:active{
    cursor:move;
}
```

This won't work because it will be automatically changed by the browser to a `text` cursor when dragging. So how?

http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/uZ377/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if it truly solves your problem, but this ( http://jsfiddle.net/garretruh/pJjd4/ ) seems get rid of the text-select cursor by not making text selectable at all. Then again, you might want users to be able to select your text.

Comment: It works! But now the texts other than my `<canvas>` are now un-selectable.

Comment: Is something like this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891581/how-can-i-disable-text-selection-temporarily-using-javascript ) what you're looking for? I think in order to temporarily disable text-selection for the drag, but enable it in normal usage, Javascript is a must. Unless you want to create a pseudo-copy of the element to be dragged around until it is dropped, upon which text-selection is re-enabled.

Comment: Please, do write your code here, because jsfiddle is not available for some people.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is over a year old, but just change the * selector at the top of that JSFiddle to only match the element that you are dragging around. No Javascript required.