# Dragging Still Highlights Text

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, drawing

After reading the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891581/how-can-i-disable-text-selection-temporarily-using-javascript), I have implemented the same functionality where I check for `event.preventDefault` and either run `event.preventDefault()` or `event.returnValue = false`. This seems to have solved the problem for the user in the question but mine is still highlighting text. It **is** hitting the line `event.returnValue = false` in IE 7/8. It also works well in Firefox, Chrome, IE 9+.

A little more information: I am using a raphael canvas. I have the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events for the canvas all doing their own thing. I implemented the check for `event.preventDefault` in the `mousedown` callback function.

Comment: use css, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: the css will not work because i still want to be able to drag/draw inside of the canvas element but if the user draws outside I do not want it to highlight any text

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using jQuery, this will solve it cross-browser:

```
$(function (){
    $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        return this
            .attr('unselectable', 'on')
            .css('user-select', 'none')
            .on('selectstart', false);
    };
})();
```

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using jQuery for this application.